Как вывести изображение с веб-камеры на экран в Alt Linux при аутентификации по лицу, распознавание производится с помощью Howdy
Как вывести изображение с веб-камеры на экран в Alt Linux при аутентификации по лицу, распознавание производится с помощью Howdy,  нужно увидеть именно изображение лица на экране, сейчас появляется лишь уведомление о идентификации. Используется alt-kworkstation-10.2.1 на виртуальной машине.

Сомневаюсь, что Шигорин тут сидит. На оф форуме спрашивала?

https://github.com/boltgolt/howdy/blob/344eb342f7256154fa789cf93b5c0eff2c33c2e4/howdy/src/compare.py#L244
Вот тут забирается картинка с камеры.
Добавьте строчку, может получится
cv2.imshow("заголовок окна", frame) 

Но для начала надо подглядеть в каком контексте запускается python при аутентификации. скорее всего без дисплея. тогда стоит посмотереть как запускается это уведомление.
А хотя судя по https://github.com/boltgolt/howdy/blob/344eb342f7256154fa789cf93b5c0eff2c33c2e4/howdy/src/compare.py#L157C1-L158C1
дисплей будет доступен.
